# What's the expected cover time of an asymmetric random walk on a circle?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, puzzle, random-walk, stopping-times

Given n points on a circle. Assume that you start at one of the points, and every step you walk clockwise with pobability p, walk counterclockwise with probabilty 1-p. What's the expected value of the steps until you have visited all of the points at least once?
When p=0.5, the problem is easy to solve, so I want to solve this general version.

Comment: I think the way to go here is to consider a process $X_k$, such that $X_k$ is $1$ if you take a counterclockwise step, and $-1$ if you take a clockwise step. Then consider $S_k = \sum_j^k X_j$ and you are asking the question what is the first time that $|S_k| = n$

Comment: The stopping time is not what you described~ The condition in your last sentence is not necessary.

Comment: @a_student =..=

Comment: what point exactly does bother you?

Comment: @a_student Due to the asymmetry, it's hard to compute the additional expected steps from one state to another(here, 'state' means the set of points you have visited).

Comment: @a_student I don't think $|S_k|=n$ is necessarily the first time you have visited every point.  You could consider going halfway around one direction, then reversing and going all the way around the other direction until you visited every point.

Comment: @user6247850 see my answer below

Comment: @user6247850 turns out I was wrong indeed